# Detect available and idle cores in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

I frequently use `parallel::detectCores()` in `R`, to get the number of CPU cores on a host, for parallelized computation. I would like to get a count of the number of **available** and **idle** cores for my computation. If some of the cores are being used by another user I don't want to hog them for my program. Is there a way we can do this programmatically?

Comment: I don't think this is possible but I'll be interested in knowing it also !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a method that uses system commands and regex to get the idle time of each processor...  this should probably be extended to a function with options to allow for other performance metrics (i.e. system time).

```
library(doParallel)

# total cores
N_CORES <- detectCores()

# create list for readable lapply output
cores <- lapply(1:N_CORES, function(x) x - 1)
names(cores) <- paste0('CPU', 1:N_CORES - 1)

# use platform specific system commands to get idle time
proc_idle_time <- lapply(cores, function(x) {
  if (.Platform$OS.type == 'windows') {
    out <- system2(
      command = 'typeperf', 
      args = c('-sc', 1, sprintf('"\\processor(%s)\\%% idle time"', x)),
      stdout = TRUE)
    idle_time <- strsplit(out[3], ',')[[1]][2]
    idle_time <- as.numeric(gsub('[^0-9.]', '', idle_time))
  } else {
    # assumes linux
    out <- system2(
      command = 'mpstat', 
      args = c('-P', x),
      stdout = TRUE)
    idle_time <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(out[4], ' {2,}'))[12])
  }
  idle_time
})
```